# How do I retrieve an XUL element’s actual width and height?

Tags: firefox-addon, element, xul

I wanna get the actual width of a `<xul:hbox>` element for presentation. How can I get it? I see HTML element has offsetWidth attribute but I can't find this attribute in XUL element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) or the older `element.boxObject.width`.