# Get the width in pixels of an element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, width

I want to get the width of an element including border, margin and padding.

I know using `$(input).width()` or `$(input).css('width')` give the width of the element.

But here is the requirement.

Suppose I created a text box like follows:

```
<input type='text' id='txtBox' name='txtBox' style='width:100%' />
```

or

```
<input type='text' id='txtBox' name='txtBox' style='width:auto' />
```

If I get the width using either $input.css('width') or $input.width(). I am not able to get the width in pixels. I am using jquery1.3.2.

Comment: @tster - I am testing using Firefox. But I want to work this for all browsers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997419/how-do-i-retreive-an-xul-elements-actual-width-and-height?

Comment: This should work, **when** do you try to acess the width()  ?

Comment: @Dr.Molle - I am having a jquery ui sortable list. I am setting the width of all the list items as 'auto'. When I am sorting I need the width of the list element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should work just fine.

You are maybe missing to wrap your code into `jQuery(document).ready()`.

See. http://www.jsfiddle.net/Cs4bu/1/

Comment: Thats working great there. But I don't know why is it not working in my application. I have the jQuery(document).ready().